# UIPopoverController disappears when ipad orientation changes

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipopovercontroller

Popover appears properly when I click on button.

When orientation changes then it disappears & leave a black topbar.

Below is the reference image.

Can anyone suggest, why it is happening?

[image]

[image]

My Code:

```
EBFirstViewController *firstViewController = [[EBFirstViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    navigationController.delegate = self;

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];
    self.popoverController = popover;
    popoverController.delegate = self;

    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 527.0f)];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:settingsBtn.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

For That following code help to solve your problem.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newStatusBarOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    // a cheat, so that we can dismiss all our popovers, if they're open.

    if (ObjPopover) {
        // if we're actually showing the menu, and not the about box, close out any active menu dialogs too
        if (menuPopoverVC && menuPopoverVC == ObjPopover.contentViewController)
            [menuPopoverVC.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [menuPopoverPC dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        menuPopoverPC = nil;
    }
}


- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    // the user (not us) has dismissed the popover, let's cleanup.
    ObjPopover = nil;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to remove the popover.